# Can we prove that the identity permutation is even this way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, permutations

We know that a permutation is $even$ if it can be written as a product of $even$ number of transpositions.

I read so many proofs regarding the parity of the identity permutation but found them all too long and sometimes hard.
I tried this:

Let $B$ be an even permutation, then $B^{-1}$ is also even. Same if odd ($i.e.$ both a permutation and its inverse are products of the same number of transpositions).

The identity permutation $id$ = $B$$B^{-1}$, so if $B$ is a product of $r$ transpositions, then $B^{-1}$ is also a product of $r$ transpositions. Therefore the identity is a product of $2r$ transpositions and hence $even$.

Comment: One could alternatively prove the proposition by pointing out that $0$ is an even number.

Comment: @CatalinZara: Yes I corrected it. Is my proof correct?

Comment: @Arthur: Mmmm, why? didn't get it.

Comment: The identity premutation may be written as the product of no transpositions. Zero is an even number, therefore the identity permutation is even.

Comment: @Arthur. Oh right! But is my proof acceptable?

Comment: @Nour If you already know that the product of two even (or two odd) permutations is even. This essentially amounts to knowing that the parity does not depend on the choice of transpositions.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen so what?

Comment: So the proofs you have looked at are proving that the identity permutation cannot be expressed as the product of an odd (finite) number of transpositions (from which it follows that any permutation that can be expressed as a product of transpositions can either be expressed only as a product of an even number or only as the product of an odd number of transpositions). That the identity can be expressed as a product of some even number (e.g. 0) of transpositions is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

In your proof, you are assuming that a permutation cannot be both even and odd (for otherwise, you could express B as a product of an even number of transpositions, and B^(-1) as a product of an odd number of transpositions, and then your proof falls flat). To prove that a permutation cannot be BOTH even and odd, you need the fact that identity can only be expressed as a product of an even number of permutations. So you do need an alternative approach to proving this result. That's why most proofs are lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

Let  P be a permutation... P is either odd or even  so if P is odd then it's inverse also odd.. We know that identity permutation is product of a permutation and it's inverse .. So identity permutation will be product of P and it's inverse.. Since both permutation is odd so their product is even... Similarly we can prove for P is even permutation... Thank you